# How to keep the triangle shape when exporting triangles from R to Excel?

Tags: r, excel

I've used the ChainLadder library to construct development triangles. My issue is that when exporting them using write.xlsx2, they end up being formatted as a regular table instead of a triangle.

I'm probably missing something very obvious since this should be pretty straightforward. Have tried messing around with the write.xlsx2 but I don't think that's it, the issue is probably with how the as.triangle object is constructed?

Thank you.

```
for (i in unique(datSCR$SPC)){

  datSCRtmp<-subset(datSCR, SPC==i)

  tri=as.triangle(datSCRtmp,
                  origin="SC",
                  dev="dev",
                  value="CS")

  write.xlsx2(tri, "TrianglesSCR.xlsx", sheetName = i,
              col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
}
```

And what I get in excel :

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reshape()` function from reshape packages.

```
reshaped_triangle = reshape(triangle_as_column, timevar = "dev", idvar = "origin", direction = "wide")
```

You before need to transform your triangle in columnar format through the function

```
triangle_as_column = as.LongTriangle(triangle, varnames = names(dimnames(triangle)),value.name = "value", na.rm = TRUE)
```